# OpenGL example to render bitmap to MediaCodec surface

Tags: android, opengl-es, surfaceview, android-bitmap, android-mediacodec

I am looking for an example on how to render a bitmap to the surface provided by MediaCodec so I can encode and then mux them into mp4 video.

The closest well know example I see is this [EncodeAndMuxTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/EncodeAndMuxTest.java.txt). Unfortunately with my limited OpenGL knowledge I have not been able to convert the example to use bitmaps instead of the raw OpenGL Frames it currently generates. Here is the example's Frame generation Method.

```
private void generateSurfaceFrame(int frameIndex) {

    frameIndex %= 8;
    int startX, startY;
    if (frameIndex < 4) {
        // (0,0) is bottom-left in GL
        startX = frameIndex * (mWidth / 4);
        startY = mHeight / 2;
    } else {
        startX = (7 - frameIndex) * (mWidth / 4);
        startY = 0;
    }

    GLES20.glClearColor(TEST_R0 / 255.0f, TEST_G0 / 255.0f, TEST_B0 / 255.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    GLES20.glScissor(startX, startY, mWidth / 4, mHeight / 2);
    GLES20.glClearColor(TEST_R1 / 255.0f, TEST_G1 / 255.0f, TEST_B1 / 255.0f, 1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
}
```

Can someone please show me how to modify this to render a bitmap instead or point me to an example that does this? I'm assuming that this is all I need to do in order to get bitmaps to render to the surface (but I may be wrong).

Edit: this is the method I replaced generateSurfaceFrame with that doesn't create any input to the encoder surface so far:

```
private int generatebitmapframe()
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

    try {

        int id = _context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/other", null, _context.getPackageName());

        // Temporary create a bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_context.getResources(), id);

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

        if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
        {
            // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

            // Set filtering
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

            // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
        }

        if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
        }

        //Utils.testSavebitmap(bmp, new File(OUTPUT_DIR, "testers.bmp").getAbsolutePath());
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

Comment: solved? please share fix code

Comment: No unfortunately the understanding of OpenGL required for something like this is a substantial investment in time that I haven't been able to make yet. Also unfortunately, the people who have figured this out have not been able to share an actual working example ;/

Comment: ok thank you ............

Comment: @grizzly did you find a solution?

Comment: @user924 no unfortunately :| easy way for this purpose is FFmpeg or bigFlake by google

Comment: While I don't have a working solution yet, I can tell you what's wrong with your code first and foremost. Namely, you are just loading a bitmap into a texture, but you're not doing anything with that. The BigFlake code should already make the encoder's EGLSurface current, so that's ok. Then you need to render your texture to that surface in order to see something out.

Comment: Also, if your source is a bitmap, I think you'd be better off to dequeue an input buffer from your MediaCodec instance and write the image to that directly, then queue it back.